# Problem running flutter with mapbox-gl in ios

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, token, mapbox-gl

I am trying to install mapbox in my flutter app:

`dependencies:`

`mapbox_gl: ^0.16.0`

and I have been following the guidelines from https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install/ and https://pub.dev/packages/mapbox_gl#secret-mapbox-access-token to start using it in iOs xcode simulator.

When flutter automatically runs pod install, it comes up with the error

> Error output from CocoaPods: ↳          % Total    % Received % Xferd
> Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
> Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed      0    39    0     0
> 0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0        curl:
> (22) The requested URL returned error: 401

My .netrc is located in ~/ directory.

~/.netrc reads as follows:

> machine api.mapbox.com
>
> login mapbox
>
> password sk.xxxxxxx.....xxxxxx

and the secret token does have the Download:read scope

Am I missing something?

I have tried running flutter in macos directly and it works perfectly,I have tried to install mapbox.gl packages from xcode project also and it works, but when I run flutter it tries to install them via pod eitherway and it comes up with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Had seemingly the same issue locally, deleted and re-created the .netrc file using vi which resolved the issue (previously had been using TextEdit). I followed steps below:

1. Open Terminal and navigate to the home directory by typing cd ~ and pressing Enter.
2. Create a new file named .netrc by typing vi .netrc and pressing Enter. This will open an empty file in the terminal.
3. Press i to enter insert mode and paste the following lines:

```
    machine api.mapbox.com
    login mapbox
    password <sk.xxxx>
```

Note: Replace <sk.xxxx> with your Mapbox key.

4. Press the Esc key to exit insert mode.
5. Type :w and press Enter to save the file.
6. Type :q and press Enter to quit from the file.
7. Re-run the app.

Answer (score 0):

If you still get 401 error after following [these steps](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/guides/install), you can update your PATH variable for the current session at the command line for .netrc file.

Try this before `pod install` or `flutter run` command.

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/USERNAME/.netrc"
```